# Подправить код, который пишет все подряд, и перезаписывает снова

Tags: php, запись

Помогите пожалуйста подправить код, который записывает в файл данные с формы методом POST из формы выбора changed_form
Вот скрипт

```
<?php
$file = fopen("save_form_type.txt", "wb");
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    fwrite($file, $key . '=>' . $val . "\n");
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

пишет в файл этоc "hanged_form=>art_0004" (без кавычек).
Из этого нужно только art_0004 и что бы запись шла каждый раз с новой строки.

Comment: это `$key . '=>' . `   не пробовали убрать?

Comment: помогло! осталась то что я хотел, но не решена проблема с записью каждый раз в новый файл, и например в другую папку. А файлы назвать датой с временем

Answer (score 1):

я добавил функцию записи в файл + запись будет с новой строки

```
 <?php
    $file = fopen("save_form_type.txt", "a"); // writing to the file append
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
    {
        fwrite($file, $val . "\r\n");
    }
    fclose($file);
 ?>
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо.  А что дописать, что бы каждый следующий раз запись происходила с новой строки, не стирая предыдущее

Comment: я добавил все теперь работает как вам надо